# printing an iframe with data created from code not is not working

Tags: javascript, pdf, iframe, jspdf, node-pdfkit

I have some sample code located on a branch for pdfkit at:

https://github.com/EricG-Personal/pdf_printing/tree/feature/from_pdfkit

The code I am using to create a simple PDF with pdfkit is:

```
var doc = new PDFDocument( { size: 'legal' } );

this.stream = doc.pipe( blobStream() );

doc.fontSize( 9 );
doc.font( 'Times-Roman' );
doc.text( "hello, world! I'm really here" );
doc.rect( 10, 10, 100, 100 ).stroke();
doc.end();

this.stream.on( 'finish', function() 
{
    console.log( "Stream Finished" );

    this.setState( { pdfData: this.stream.toBlobURL( 'application/pdf' ) } );
}.bind( this ) );
```

For jsPDF - https://github.com/EricG-Personal/pdf_printing/tree/feature/from_jspdf

```
var doc = new jsPDF({unit: 'pt', format: 'legal'});
var someText = "hello, world!";
var topCoordinate = 72;
var leftCoordinate = 72;
var padding = 8;

doc.setFont( "helvetica" );
doc.setFontSize( 24 );

var lineHeight      = doc.getLineHeight();
var textWidth       = doc.getTextWidth( someText );
var rectHeight      = ( lineHeight + ( padding * 2 ) );
var halfRectHeight  = rectHeight / 2;
var halfLineHeight  = lineHeight / 2;
var textYCoordinate = topCoordinate + halfRectHeight + halfLineHeight;

console.log( "Height: " + lineHeight );
console.log( "Width: " + textWidth );

doc.setDrawColor( 255, 0, 0 );
doc.rect( leftCoordinate, topCoordinate, textWidth, rectHeight );
doc.text( someText, leftCoordinate + padding, textYCoordinate );

doc.setDrawColor( 0, 0, 0 );
doc.rect( leftCoordinate, textYCoordinate - lineHeight, textWidth, lineHeight );

var blob   = doc.output( 'bloburl' );
var mythis = this;

setTimeout( function() 
{ 
    console.log( "Setting State" );

    mythis.setState({pdfData: blob});
}, 5000);
```

In both cases, the PDF data renders correctly in the iframe and I end up calling:

```
window.frames["pdf_doc"].focus();
window.frames["pdf_doc"].print();
```

when the onLoad function of the iframe triggers.

However, the page that is to actually be printed is blank.

Answer (score 0):

it works in Safari, but not in Firefox. I think you using the wrong Key for the Array:

```
window.frames[0].focus();
window.frames[0].print();
```

works for me.

```
console.log(window.frames);
```

Look a the Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/frames

Comment: I am using Safari. It does not work. I am using the correct key.

Comment: Are you sure you are trying to print the same data I am?

Comment: sorry, i used the code from github. Could you upload the SRC?

Comment: The github project is up-to-date. It is annoying that you do not see the same behavior. Are you using the latest version of Safari on the latest version of OS X? Oh, you were correct that the index for frames should be an integer values. String indexes which correspond to the ID of the frame does not work across all browsers. Works on safari.